# DRY-ing jQuery code for portfolio site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently working on my portfolio site and it's all great, but I'm unsure how to DRY my jQuery. I'm repeating myself a lot in the jQuery and it's just messy.

**HTML:**

```
 <div id="footer-start" class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">

        <ul class="nav nav-pills footer-nav">
          <li><a href="#" class="loadHide" id="clickPortfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="loadHide" id="clickAbout">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="loadHide" id="clickContact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>

        <span>Click to expand</span>
        <img src="img/arrow.png" alt="" class="loadHide">
      </div>
    </div>

<div id="footer-portfolio" class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-4 col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">

        <a class="lightbox" href="img/" title=""><img src="img" width="150px" height="150px" /></a>

        <a class="lightbox" href="img/" title="(WIP)"><img src="img/" width="80px" height="150px" /></a>

      </div>
    </div>

<div id="footer-about" class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <h3>About me<small></small></h3>

        <p>Paragraph</p>
      </div>
    </div>

        <div id="footer-contact" class="row">
      <h3>Questions<small></small></h3>

      <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 contact-form">
        <form id="contact" method="post" action="send.php"  class="form" role="form">

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 form-group">
              <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text" required autofocus />
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 form-group">
              <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="email" required />
            </div>
          </div> 

          <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Message" rows="7"></textarea>
          <br />

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 form-group">
              <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </div>

        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {




 var $footerPortfolio = $('#footer-portfolio'),
          $footerAbout = $('#footer-about'),
          $footerContact = $('#footer-contact'),
          $footerSent = $('#footer-contact-sent'),
          $clickPortfolio = $('#clickPortfolio'),
          $clickAbout = $('#clickAbout'),
          $clickContact = $('#clickContact'),
          $arrowImg = $('#footer-start img'),
          $arrowTxt = $('#footer-start span'),
          $loadHide = $('.loadHide');
          sentUrl = window.location.href;

      $loadHide.hide();

      $arrowImg.hover(function() {
        $arrowTxt.show('fade', 800);
        },function() {
          $arrowTxt.hide('fade');
        });

      $clickPortfolio.click(function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        $loadHide.slideUp(500);
        $footerPortfolio.slideToggle(500);
      });

      $clickAbout.click(function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        $loadHide.slideUp(500);
        $footerAbout.slideToggle(500);
      });

      $clickContact.click(function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        $loadHide.slideUp(500);
        $footerContact.slideToggle(500);
      });

      if (sentUrl.search("#sent") >= 0) {
        $footerContact.slideUp(500);
        $footerSent.slideDown(800).delay(1000).slideUp(800);
      }
    });
```

I got a bit cleaner, and would love some feedback on this solution.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  var $footerPortfolio = $('#footer-portfolio'),
      $footerAbout = $('#footer-about'),
      $footerContact = $('#footer-contact'),
      $footerSent = $('#footer-contact-sent');

  var $clickPortfolio = $('#clickPortfolio'),
      $clickAbout = $('#clickAbout'),
      $clickContact = $('#clickContact');

  var $arrowImg = $('#footer-start img'),
      $arrowTxt = $('#footer-start span');

  var $loadHide = $('.loadHide');

  var sentUrl = window.location.href;

  $loadHide.hide();

  $arrowImg.hover(function() {
    $arrowTxt.show('fade', 800);
    },function() {
      $arrowTxt.hide('fade');
    });

 function myClick(obj) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (obj == $footerPortfolio) {
      $footerAbout.slideUp(500);
      $footerContact.slideUp(500);
      obj.slideToggle(500);
    } else if (obj == $footerAbout) {
      $footerPortfolio.slideUp(500);
      $footerContact.slideUp(500);
      obj.slideToggle(500);
    } else if (obj == $footerContact) {
      $footerPortfolio.slideUp(500);
      $footerAbout.slideUp(500);
      obj.slideToggle(500);
    }
  }

  $clickPortfolio.click(function() {
    myClick($footerPortfolio); }
  );

  $clickAbout.click(function() {
    myClick($footerAbout); }
  );

  $clickContact.click(function() {
    myClick($footerContact); }
  );

  if (sentUrl.search("#sent") >= 0) {
    $footerContact.slideUp(500);
    $footerSent.slideDown(800).delay(1000).slideUp(800);
  }

});
```

Even better:

```
 function myClick(obj) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (obj.css('display') == 'none'){
      $loadHide.slideUp(500);
      obj.slideToggle(500);
    } else if (obj.css('display') != 'none') {
      obj.slideUp(500);
    }
  }
```

Comment: This would be *so* much easier using a library like Knockout JS. Check it out, you'll never code using jQuery .on selectors again.

Answer (score 7):

The way you define `sentUrl` as a global variable is either buggy (if it's unintentional) or deceptive (if it's intentional).

```
var $footerPortfolio = $('#footer-portfolio'),
      …
      $loadHide = $('.loadHide');
      sentUrl = window.location.href;
```

Since the difference between a local and a global variable hinges on the distinction between a comma and semicolon, I prefer to see such multi-line definitions to be written as

```
var $footerPortfolio = $('#footer-portfolio');
var $footerAbout = $('#footer-about');
var $footerContact = $('#footer-contact');
var $footerSent = $('#footer-contact-sent');
var $clickPortfolio = $('#clickPortfolio');
var $clickAbout = $('#clickAbout');
var $clickContact = $('#clickContact');
var $arrowImg = $('#footer-start img');
var $arrowTxt = $('#footer-start span');
var $loadHide = $('.loadHide');
var sentUrl = window.location.href;
```

If it *is* intentionally a global variable, then fix your indentation and add vertical spacing so that

```
sentUrl = window.location.href;
```

stands alone.

Comment: It makes a lot of sense and didn't realize it myself, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

### Be Consistent

You create two different styles of Image tags,

- self closing

  > ```
  > <img src="img/" width="80px" height="150px" />
  > ```
- not closed

  > ```
  > <img src="img/arrow.png" alt="" class="loadHide">
  > ```

In HTML5 it doesn't matter which way you do this as both will work,  but you should stay consistent,  personally I use the self closing image tags.

---

### Reduce Clutter

I noticed that you do this a couple of times as well

> ```
> <h3>About me<small></small></h3>
> ```

Why do you have the `<small>` tag in there with nothing in it?  If you don't need it there get rid of it.  Extra tags add to clutter, they are essentially dead code that could be inadvertently visible or move things around on the page in a way that you didn't anticipate.

---

### Use Standard Formatting

Use proper indentation and newline characters throughout your HTML.

> ```
> <a class="lightbox" href="img/" title=""><img src="img" width="150px" height="150px" /></a>
> ```

Should look like this

```
<a class="lightbox" href="img/" title="">
    <img src="img" width="150px" height="150px" />
</a>
```

This makes it easier for the next person to read through your HTML

Comment: you are welcome. All of these things make it easier to maintain as well.

Answer (score 5):

You can move all of the `click` functionality into one function:

```
function myClick(obj)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    $loadHide.slideUp(500);
    obj.slideToggle(500);
}
```

Then call that function inside each of your click mappings:

```
$clickPortfolio.click(function() {myClick($footerPortfolio)});

$clickAbout.click(function() {myClick($footerAbout)});

$clickContact.click(function() {myClick($footerContact)});
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for but didn't know. I'll be using this for reference in the future.

Comment: The issue I'm having now is the page loads, slides it all up and the last element stays displayed. In this case '$footerContact'.

Comment: I think the bug was occurring because the myClick() code was actually getting called. I have updated my answer. All that should be needed is to wrap that call in an anonymous function.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I just realized I made a mistake in the HTML with what I want to hide. I actually want to hide the "footer-portfolio", "footer-about" and "footer-contact" divs and toggle them via the buttons. With the code you've updated it does that but the '$loadHide.slideUp' followed by the toggle is making it have a non-stop cycle of sliding down. Any suggestions?

Comment: I've done the following but wondering if there is a cleaner way.  
  function myClick(obj) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($clickPortfolio) {
      $footerAbout.slideUp(500);
      $footerContact.slideUp(500);
      obj.slideToggle(500);
    }
  }

Comment: You could even define a secondary `function attachEvents($button, $footer) { button.click(function() { myClick($footer); }); }` and then simply invoke as `attachEvents($clickPortfolio, $footerPortfolio)` and similar.

Answer (score 5):

Part 1: Introduce a "data-myapp-target" attribute to create a mapping between the links and the footers. The "myapp" portion is just to avoid collision with anything else that might be using a similarly named "data-" attribute; use whatever value is appropriate for your application.

```
      <li><a href="#" class="loadHide" id="clickPortfolio" data-myapp-target="footer-portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="loadHide" id="clickAbout" data-myapp-target="footer-about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="loadHide" id="clickContact" data-myapp-target="footer-contact">Contact</a></li>
```

Part 2: Use that attribute in your jQuery code:

```
  $loadHide.click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    $loadHide.slideUp(500);
    $("#" + $(this).data("myapp-target")).slideToggle(500);
  });
```

This code assumes that the data-myapp-target attribute will correspond to the id of another element.

Comment: This is a great idea. It's exactly what `data-` attributes are for.

Comment: This idea isn't bad, but the code should probably read `$(this).data("myapp-target")` instead.

Comment: @Schism Thanks for that suggestion! Answer has been updated.

Answer (score 2):

From your last update:

```
function myClick(obj) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (obj.css('display') == 'none'){
      $loadHide.slideUp(500);
      obj.slideToggle(500);
    } else if (obj.css('display') != 'none') {
      obj.slideUp(500);
    }
}
```

You don't need the nested if, as the object or is visible or is not. Moreover, you can pass an extra parameter that you default to 500 for the duration of the animation.

```
function myClick(obj, duration) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // Defaults an optional parameter for the duration of the animation.
    duration = duration || 500;

    if (obj.is(":visible")){
      $loadHide.slideUp(delay);
    }
    obj.slideToggle(delay);
}
```